# Is click-to-filter available on Superset similarly to e.g. Power BI?

Tags: filter

I am new to Apache Superset and I am still discovering the basic features.

I was wondering whether there is the possibility to click a graph so that it filters the rest of the report (similarly to Power BI).
Or is the filter panel the only solution?

I created the first graphs on my dashboard and I was hoping I could click on the area of the chart to make it filter for the rest of the report. Instead I only discovered I can interact with the legend of the single graph to remove categories, but not any interaction with other visuals.

Thank you in advance!